# Execute Script Functions from Firebug Console

Tags: jquery, firebug

Let's say I have script file which is work with jQuery.

```
//script.js
    shuffleGridView: function (i, j) {
        var h = this.element.find(this.options.gridSelector),
            f = i ? this.options.colsSidebarClosed : this.options.colsSidebarOpen,
            g = i ? this.options.colsSidebarOpen : this.options.colsSidebarClosed;
        if (d.AsSupport.transition && !d.AsSupport.touch) {
            j = j || 1;
            d.AsGridShuffle(h, {
                startColCount: f,
                endColCount: g,
                startIndex: j
            })
        }
    }
```

What I want to do, calling this function ( shuffleGridView) from firebug console. Is there a way to call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `shuffleGridView` is a property of an object.

If object is in global namesapace run in console with:

```
objectName.shuffleGridView(value1,value2);
```

No need to use `console.log()` from within browser console...it will run as is.

For example paste this into console:

```
var foo="bar";
foo
```

Should see `"bar"` output

Comment: Dear Charlie, I tried but no result. For instance, I took above snippet from Apple store page. There is a `window.$P` global namespace. But I can't see above function when write like this: `window.$P.shuffleGridView` Here is the link http://store.apple.com/tr/iphone/iphone-accessories/headsets#!

Comment: which file is it in...don't feel like searching for it

Comment: category.js, `as.WebSearchResults.prototype.shuffleGridView`. To call it you probably want an instance of the WebSearchResults class.

Comment: would need  a webSearchResults object for the prototype to be available